# Backing up a MySQL database remotely to a local machine with a shell command

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a remote machine with several MySQL databases that I would like to automatically back up to a local machine. Is there a shell command that I can execute from the local machine to do this? Like a remote `mysqldump`. Any help?

Comment: What is the remote box, and what is the local box? Do you have scp or sftp possibilities for copying the data dump?

Comment: Yes, I can do scp. Remote = CentOS Linux, Local = Mac OS X.

Comment: In that case, something like @Bacon suggested would probably be your best bet. Do a MySQL dump then SCP the file across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysqldump --all-databases --routines -h <ip-address> -u <user> -p > dump.sql
```

If you want to run it automatically you have to write the password next to the -p parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to do this, I wrote a cron job that would run mysqldump, .gz.tar the dump files into a date-named archive, and sftp them to a remote server.  It would not be that much of a difference to write an ssh script followed by an sftp file transfer to pull the backup instead of pushing it.